# query "select for update" in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, select

I have query = `SELECT @condi:=id FROM table WHERE id>1 LIMIT 1 for UPDATE; UPDATE table set aa="ok" WHERE id=@condi`

I used `$this->db->query(query)` but codeigniter info error
*"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update table set aa="ok" where id=@condi' at line 1" 
Miss ";"*
I use phpmyadmin execuse this query, it's result row correct not error query

maybe core codeigniter error can you help me execuse my query in codeigniter,thanks

Comment: $this->db->query(query)

change to

$this->db->query($query)

Comment: As far as I know codeigniter's active records doesn't support SELECT FOR UPDATE statement. So probably the only solution is to use query() function and build your own statement.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use query builder to prevent SQL error:

```
$query = $this->db->select()
            ->from('table')
            ->where('id >', 1)
            ->limit(1)
            ->get_compiled_select();
$data = $this->db->query("{$query} FOR UPDATE")->row_array();

$this->db->where('id', $condi)->update('table', ['aa'=>'ok']);
```

Because the Codeigniter 3 builder doesn't support `FOR UPDATE`, so I just use compiler to rebuild query.

> Codeigniter [get_compiled_select()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::get_compiled_select)
>
> [yidas/codeigniter-model - Pessimistic Locking](https://github.com/yidas/codeigniter-model#pessimistic-locking)